# Postfix cannot send to external domains

Tags: postfix, smtp, dovecot

I set up my Postfix with a sasl link to a Dovecot user / domain database.

Postfix is giving the following error message when trying to send mail to external recipients (internal are fine):

Server error: '550 5.1.1 : Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table'

```
# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = scan:127.0.0.1:10025
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = 
myhostname = (my.hostname.com)
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix_cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/postfix_key.pem
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_gid_maps = static:502
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/mailadmin
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 502
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:502
```

I've been trying different things for the past few hours, but no luck.

What could be the cause?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting mydestination yet? Postfix is trying to deliver external mail on your local machine, and having 'mydestination =' could be a factor in that.

Comment: Yes, I tried that multiple times. I just set mydestination = $myhostname in main.cf, and reloaded postfix, but that did not change anything. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After another whole day of reading documentation and tampering with settings, I was finally able to resolve the issue. The problem was in mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf, which had a MySQL query that did not take an argument, and therefore always returned the same result (the list of all available domains). The correct situation is when the query only returns a result when there is a match. Hopefully this helps someone else, who happens to run into the same issue.